# What is the difference between "be prepare to do something" and "be prepare do be doing something"?

Tags: grammar, difference

What is the difference between *be prepare to do* and *be prepare do be doing*? For example:

> I wasn't **prepared to live** in such horrible conitions. There isn't even a bathroom.
>
> I wasn't **prepared to be living** in such horrible conitions. There isn't even a bathroom.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"I wasn't prepared to ..."  means that I was not willing to do 'thing'.

"I wasn't prepared to be ..." means that I did not expect to be 'thing', and that I had not prepared for it in advance.